# Dcos on premises , How out side world reach to docker container if we are using mesos-dns?

Tags: docker, haproxy, mesos, mesosphere

In Dcos on premises , How outside world reach to docker container if we are using **mesos-dns for service discovery** ?

Lets say my mesos domain  is marathon.mesos
I have deployed Nginx container using Marathon framework and mesos-dns discover as "nginx.marathon.mesos" . Within the cluster i can access http://nginx.marathon.mesos via web brower , thats no issue.

But in outside the cluster( in public world) that nginx container server need to present as "abc.xyz.com" 
when someone type abc.xyz.com , **traffic should route to nginx container**, If i use mesos-dns for service discovery how can we deal with this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you would need to setup a node with a public IP and run a task with a reverse proxy on there (like in the tutorials) that forwards to the internal mesos dns backed service.

If you have more questions or need follow up on this one, please contact mesosphere support.

Answer (score 0):

I have resoved this problem. you can refer the document,https://docs.mesosphere.com/tutorials/publicapp/ 
If your app running on port:80, you can access from the public slave node's domain.

If you have any question , you can reply to me.